# How can I remember how to play the Harp?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

So, I just got my first song using the harp, and I've totally forgotten how the song went. I thought, no big deal, there's always a reminder somewhere. After digging around for a while, and even returning to the spot I learned it, I really just can't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: +1 *Excellent* question. I'm sure you're not the only one which was confused by this. It's a very unusual system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are actually no songs for you to select on the harp. You just play the harp in certain places. The only difference between initiating one song or another is where you play the harp.

I understand the confusion as all other zelda games with instruments had specific patterns you had to play to activate the song. (Which is a better way of doing it IMHO)

Comment: So all I do is pull out the Harp where I need it and swing around for a bit?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: Pretty much.  It's more about keeping rhythm with the beat than memorizing notes.

Comment: “Which is a better way of doing it” – totally agree with that. Now the harp just sounds the same, and the actual melody comes from somewhere else (or Fi). This is especially weird with the Goddess Melody where there is actually harp play in the music…

Comment: I just don't understand, what beat?

Comment: I am having a problem getting the harp to play at ALL. I'm at the point where you need to get the two windmills to point at the light tower. I've done this (via retrieving the propeller with the robot). A new platform has appeared at the light tower. So, I go to the light tower and....can't get the harp to come out of my inventory!! HELP!

Comment: @ElLoco You should [ask your own question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for this as it is a separate problem.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've figured it out, in large part to Ronan's answer.

There are basically 2 types of places that you play songs.

The first is where blessed butterflies appear. Basically try to follow the beat as given by the movement of the wii mote, it should be close enough after a second or two.

The second is in places where you have to specifically play a song. Some kind of a pulsating circle will show up. Try to move the wii remote to the rhythm of the beat.

While there are technically songs, it really doesn't affect much how you play. All it will do is allow you to play the harp in the right spot, with the right tempo coming from the pulsating circle.

If you are playing a song somewhere that just doesn't seem to work, and isn't one of the two above items, it's probably because it won't work, period. Keep looking for a better place to play, etc.